# Compose/bind "Except"s with varying error types by common error type class

Tags: haskell

I have some functions returning `Except` types (from [transformers](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.12/transformers-0.4.2.0/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html) package) with varying error types but all implementing the class `Show`. In case of an error I just want to print the message.

What's the best way to compose/bind them?

I could convert the error types for every `fun*` before `(=<<)`, or write a `(=<<)` wrapper that takes all showable types and converts them to `String`s (`RankNTypes`?), but that feels ugly. Is there a better way, using the type system, that handles all that automatically?

Example code:

```
module Main where

import           Control.Monad.Trans.Except
import qualified Data.Text as T

type StrError = String
type TxtError = T.Text

funA :: String -> Except StrError String
funA = return

funB :: String -> Except TxtError T.Text
funB = return . T.pack

fun :: String -> IO ()
fun s = case runExcept (funB =<< funA s) of
            Left e  -> putStrLn $ show e
            Right _ -> return ()

main :: IO ()
main = fun "foo"
```

Comment: [Control.Exception](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Exception.html) has the SomeException type which seems to be what you are looking for...

Comment: @Alec: Are you suggesting to make my error types instances of `Exception` class and use `SomeException`? (Because despite the name, `Except` has nothing to do with exceptions). Sounds like a solution that would work, I just can't really tell if that's a good one or not.

Comment: After more poking around, I'm not sure that helps at all - the `Exception` class requires you to implement `displayException :: e -> String`, which kind of defies the point.

Comment: @Alec: "Default implementation: show."

Comment: Oh, missed that. Then yeah, you could simply derive `SomeException`, and now you can wrap your exception types in this. Alternately you could make your own `data Exception = forall e . Show e => Exception e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to create a new `Exception` type (but this does require `-XExistentialQuantification`) of exceptions that can be shown.

```
data Exception = forall e . Show e => Exception e
```

Then, all that needs to be changed to make your code compile is the type signatures.

```
funA :: String -> Except Exception String
funB :: String -> Except Exception T.Text
```

Additionally, whenever you create an exception (of which there are no examples in your code above) you now need to wrap it in the `Exception` constructor.

```
throwsA :: String -> Except Exception String
throwsA = throwE . Exception

throwsB :: T.Text -> Except Exception T.Text
throwsB = throwE . Exception
```

**EDIT** I would encourage you to make new types for your exceptions (with appropriate `Show`) then derive `Exception` from [Control.Exception](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Exception.html). That is more overhead, but it may benefit you afterwards if you ever need to switch back and forth between heterogeneous exception types. This is the way I would do it.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
module Main where

import Data.Typeable
import Control.Exception
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Control.Monad

newtype StrError = StrError String deriving (Show,Typeable)
newtype TxtError = TxtError T.Text deriving (Show,Typeable)

instance Exception StrError
instance Exception TxtError

toErr :: Exception e => Except e a -> Except SomeException a
toErr = mapExcept (either (Left . toException) Right)


funA :: String -> Except StrError String
funA = return

funB :: String -> Except TxtError T.Text
funB = return . T.pack

throwsA :: String -> Except StrError String
throwsA = throwE . StrError

throwsB :: T.Text -> Except TxtError T.Text
throwsB = throwE . TxtError


fun :: String -> IO ()
fun s = case runExcept $ (toErr . funA >=> toErr . funB) s of
            Left e  -> putStrLn $ displayException e
            Right _ -> return ()

main :: IO ()
main = fun "foo"
```

Comment: Will go through that in detail tomorrow, but from what I could see so far it would be better to write my own error/exception existential type (with Show constraint). Making the errors an instance of `Control.Exception` would be misleading because they are not supposed to be thrown, just returned. Additionally it would reduce the number of instance declarations and - if I'm not mistaken - this approach would work immediately with any `Show e => Except e`.

Comment: If you are sure you won't throw exceptions, that is indeed probably the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

`withExceptT T.unpack . funB =<< funA s`. Your show is superfluous.

Using `Control.Lens`:

`fun = void . _Left putStrLn . runExcept . (withExceptT T.unpack . funB <=< funA)`

Comment: This is not exactly what I asked. I mentioned your approach: "I could convert the error types for every fun* [...]" - the problem is: this is a lot of boilerplate code when there are loads of calls with different error types.